# Starting activity from main activity with title name change

Tags: android, android-activity

I have main activity in which my app name is `Bluetooth services`. From this main activity I start another activity but it still got the same name(title same ) and I want that now the title name is change into `connectivity panel` rather than `Bluetooth services`.

Here is my code :

```
 public void listItemClick(View v){
      temp=(TextView)v
      String info=temp.getText().toString();
      Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Connectivity Panel.class);
      startActivity(intent);       
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in `Connectivity Panel.java` :

```
setTitle("Your Title");
```

Or do that on `Manifest.xml`, found your `Connectivity Panel` and add:

```
android:label="Your Title"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change the activity title in your androidmanifest.xml**. Both the activities are probably referring to the same string resource. Or if referencing different resources both have the same value.

```
<activity
     android:name="your.package.name.YourActivity"
     android:label="@string/yout_activity_title" 
     ....
     ....
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you design your app and layout.

the answer most probably is in the string values. look in res, scroll to string, and see if that's where you want to change.

really, if you shows your layout, it would be much easier to see where's the problem is.